# Using boost::mapped_file with wchar *

Tags: c++, boost, wchar-t

I want to ask how to use `boost::iostreams::mapped_file` with `wchar_t *`. Currently, I found the following:

```
boost::iostreams::mapped_file reader("input.txt" , mapped_file::readonly);
char const * it = reader.const_begin();
char const * endit = reader.const_end();
```

As I see, the interface does only allow `char *`, but I need to read a Vietnamese corpus (encoding UTF-16 LE). The reason I ask is that all previous assignments I use this, so If there is someway I can reuse these codes again.

Comment: I would think you could just cast it. (Or `reinterpret_cast` if you like the C++-style casts)

Comment: @immibis does `reinterpret_cast` take care of little endian or big endian in this case?

Comment: Good point. It will not.

Comment: @HuyTranQ: Are you running on an x86 computer or not?  If it's x86, it's LE anyway, so no need for endian conversion.

Comment: @JohnZwinck unfortunately, i'm running on x64 architecture (Windows)

Comment: @HuyTranQ: That's not unfortunate!  x64 is also little endian.  So you can simply cast the result, yes?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Thank you, it worked!

Comment: Mandatory: http://commandcenter.blogspot.de/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html?m=1